# Dynamically create or set the return type of a function in the function

Tags: c#, generics, types

I am attempting to create a function where the return type is determined at run-time. I know I could just return an `object` or `dynamic`, however my aim is to have the typed `object` returned, and be recognized by the compiler and InteliSense.

I know I could cast my `object` after it has been returned and that would be the easiest thing to do to implement this, but that is just not the programming spirit.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to create

**Note**: I do not actually want Buttons and Grids... that is just for this example.

```
Type T;
public T Question(bool aBool)
{
    if (aBool)
    {
        T = typeof(Button);
        return new Button();
    }
    else
    {
        T = typeof(Grid);
        return new Grid();
    }
}
```

Now, this obviously doesn't work and I understand why. But I want to know if anyone has a way that does work, or if this is not possible with the current state of C#.

Edit: A response to comments... I understand this would seem like "magic", and I do understand that the compiler will have to figure out what my result is for this to work. The compiler/Intellisense/Visual Studio already does this for many other things. While these things are can  simple like detecting unreachable code, or drawing visual previews. I am curious if this is an implemented feature.

Comment: Unclear what you trying to achieve. It feels you want compiler do magic by predicting results of execution of the code some time in the future: " return type is determined at run-time ... recognized by the compiler".

Comment: How can the compiler determine the type for inteliSense when it isn't resolved until runtime? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Even with generics, the compiler still needs to be able to determine the type at compile time.  It sounds like you have a bad abstraction here, maybe if we knew what problem you were trying to solve we could advise a better course of action...

Comment: This seems like an attempt to do something that will fail logically at some point. As for this code, keep in mind you can only `return (T)someObject;` - not any other strongly typed object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only possible way for the consumer of such a method to actually rely on the fact that the return type is dynamic is if, at least for that one method call, the return type is statically known at compile time.

There is a specific feature for a method that has some type unknown at the time the method is written, but fixed when a particular call to that method is make.  That feature is called "generics".

```
public T Foo<T>()
    where T : new()
{
   return new T();
}
```

That's really the only available option for a truly dynamic return type that has much potential for really being *useful*.

If that's not what you want, or that is not a workable option for you, then odds are pretty high your method shouldn't have a dynamically changing return type.  Instead it should have a fixed return type of some more generalized type that can have multiple implementations.  Generally this would mean an interface, to which you can return one of any number of possible implementations.  This should be done if the caller doesn't need to really know or care what the implementation is, but rather all they need to know is that they are given some implementation of an interface that exposes all of what they need.  In your case, perhaps something like `Control` would be workable, if the caller only need to know that they are given some type of control, and to which the API of `Control` provides everything that they need to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic keyword in this case

eg:

```
public dynamic CreatObj(string caller)
{
    if (caller.equals("x"))
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
```

Comment: I know I could use `Dynamic`, but then it would have to be cast on the consumer side, I was looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type if it has a parameterless constructor and you mark your generic with the [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx). If you want to do more than that it get more difficult you need to use refection or activator.