# c# how to write abstract method that return enum

Tags: c#, enums, abstract

I have a base class and few classes derived from it.

I want to declare an enum in the base class as abstract and each class that derived from it will have to create its own different enum.

**How can I do it?**

I tried the following: declare an abstract method in the base class that return enum type and each class that implement it will return its own enum:

```
public abstract enum RunAtOptions();
```

But I get compile error

```
"The modifier abstract is not valid for this item"
```

Comment: An enum is a Type and you cannot have abstract types...

Comment: There are ways to emulate this but I suspect you don't really need this, it looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You mean you want to change which enum is returned based on the derived class? So, generics?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208084/dynamically-create-or-set-the-return-type-of-a-function-in-the-function

Comment: You cannot let an enum inherit from another enum, this is forbidden by the CLR. Each enum actually inherits from System.Enum and is marked as sealed. Though you can change the return type to System.Enum or use a class to emulate an enums behaviour or use generics as suggested in an answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to return the actual enum not the `enum` keyword so if you had the `enum` `MyEnumType` like this:

```
public enum MyEnumType
{
    ValueOne = 0,
    ValueTwo = 1
}

public abstract MyEnumType RunAtOptions();
```

If you wanted to modify this to use generics you could have the method return `T` and have a constraint to make `T` a struct:

```
public abstract T RunAtOptions() where T : struct;
```

C# doesn't have a generics constraint to support the enum type.

Comment: _"and each class that derived from it will have to create its own different enum"_

Comment: Can't you just constrain to System.Enum?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP wants to have a *different enum* for every derived class, not a method which returns a value from one enum.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot use the enum keyword as an abstract member.** [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354067/abstract-enum-in-c-sharp)

Alternatively, you can introduce an abstract dictionary property.

```
public class Base
{
    public abstract Dictionary<string, int> RunAtOptions { get; }
}
```

The deriving class could set the property in the constructor.

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public override Dictionary<string, int> RunAtOptions { get; }

    public Derived()
    {
        RunAtOptions = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            ["Option1"] = 1,
            ["Option2"] = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately using this method won't give you elegant compile-time checks. With this dictionary you can compare option values against entries in the dictionary like this:

```
if (someObject.Options == RunAtOptions["Option1"]) // someObject.Options is of type `int`
{
    // Do something
}
```